# How to inject a virtual widget (i.e. without adding it to the database) to the sidebar

Tags: widgets, sidebar

Can I inject a fake/dummy/virtual widget via functions.php within the loop of widgets in the sidebar? That is, without creating an actual widget in the system.

Just like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459921/how-to-inject-a-virtual-post-i-e-without-adding-it-to-the-database, but for widgets

Comment: Please explain the motivation and give a detailed example. Backend or front-end ?

Comment: I want to do it through code (functions.php), so it won't be possible for site admins to remove or modify this widget (copyright, etc.) by a simple drag and drop.